# What is the linq select syntax to check for xml data with null elements?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I'm working with xml market data and I got the almost inverse of this linq to work fine, but I'd like to return the count of the elements that have an attribute "symbol", but have a null "LastTradeDate" element. The code below is returning 0 but I know they're in there. I figured I'd spare all the xml data figuring it's likely obvious what is going on. Here's what I've got:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(addressString);
         XElement results = doc.Root.Element("results");    
var makeInfo =
         (from s in doc.Descendants("quote")
         where s.Element("LastTradeDate") == null
         && s.Attribute("symbol") != null
         select s.Attribute("symbol")).Count();
```

Comment: Are you looking for elements that have an empty LastTradeDate element", or elements that don't have a LastTradeElement?

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Possibly both, but the type I'm explicitly looking for that I know is there has an empty element.

Comment: OK, in that case `Element("LastTradeDate")` won't return null...

Comment: @ThomasLevesque Gotcha. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(addressString);
         XElement results = doc.Root.Element("results");    
var makeInfo =
         (from s in doc.Descendants("quote")
          let lastTradeDate = s.Element("LastTradeDate")
          where (lastTradeDate == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastTradeDate.Value))
          && s.Attribute("symbol") != null
          select s.Attribute("symbol")).Count();
```